# Are there any optional rules for gaining extra attacks due to high Dex?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, optional-rules, ability-scores

Are there any optional rules in D&D 5e concerning bonuses to attacks per round for characters with higher than average dexterity scores? It only makes sense to me that a fighter with a dex. of 17 would be able to wield a melee weapon at a higher rate of strikes per round than a fighter of the same level with a dex. score of 8.

Comment: *Official* optional rules, or homebrew? I cannot consider that any modern D&D designer would design something so likely to elevate Dex to a god stat.

Comment: Remember that D&D is striking a compromise between verisimilitude and functional simplicity. So there's grillions of places where "it only makes sense to me" ideas/arguments/rules are abandoned in favor of the (relatively) streamlined RAW system.

Comment: It makes even more sense that a fighter with a Strength of 17 can move a weapon more quickly than one with Strength 8.  Dexterity makes you precise, not fast.

Answer (score 16):

**No.**

But remember: a single attack in Dungeons and Dragons doesn't necessarily correspond to a single strike with a weapon - just a concerted effort to inflict harm to a target with a weapon. While it's possible to imagine that combat involves characters and monsters facing off for a few seconds, then each making one strike, and then settling back to a staring contest while they wait for the next combat round to start, that might not be appropriate if your campaign isn't based on a Kurosawa movie. A high strength character's attack might be a single mighty swing, while a high dexterity character's attack could be a series of rapid jabs.

Comment: +1 for the Kurosawa movie reference and the explanation in the last sentence.

Answer (score 12):

Nope. You only get one attack per action, unless you have the extra attack feature. You can also make additional attacks with your bonus action if using light one handed weapons (can be improved with class features or feats). No amount of dextery will affect your attack options if you are going by the rulebooks.